# Inject login details into TwitterKit

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'd like to inject or fake a login into the TwitterKit iOS SDK. I'm trying to write some unit tests for my library (which is kind of a wrapper around the most important Twitter APIs).

Unfortunately Fabric requires the user to have a system account set up or to present the OAuth screen. Is there any way to fake that login to make my test API calls succeed?

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what kind of tests you are trying to write and whether you are actually trying to make network requests during your tests.

If you are writing integration tests that have to work through the login flow the easiest way to accomplish this is to just add an account to the `ACAccountStore` by creating your own `ACAccountCredential`. One downside to this approach is that it will make a network call behind the scenes which is managed by the system, so there is no way to intercept/mock it which will likely make your tests flaky. Once you have that account added to the store it will get picked up whenever you try to go through the login flow.

If you are making network requests using the `-[TWTRAPIClient sendTwitterRequest:completion:]` method and you actually need to be logged in during these calls because you are trying to hit the Twitter API you can add a session to the `TWTRSessionStore` directly by calling `[TWTRSessionStore saveSessionWithAuthToken:authTokenSecret:completion:]`. Again, this method will make a network call that is hard to mock/intercept but that shouldn't really matter if you are making actual network requests during your tests.

If you are writing unit tests that do not need to make network requests, but you need there to be a session in the `TWTRSessionStore` you can directly save a session in the `TWTRSessionStore`. You can call `-[TWTRSessionStore saveSession:withVerification:completion:]` with a session that you create and without verification. Note, this method is private and is subject to change without notice. With that said, I don't really see any reason why we would change it anytime soon so it should be safe for you to use.

If none of that works for you, let me know more specifically what you are trying to accomplish and I can suggest other options.

Comment: That's a great answer. I'm writing unit tests at the moment and I'll soon try the last two options you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the class TWTRSessionStore doesn't have any init method. How can I see my auth token and secret in it?

Comment: You can get them from the session object you get back when you log in. Look at TWTRAuthSession.

Comment: The TWTRSessionStore can't be instantiated from code so it's not possible to create a new instance of it to store my token.

Answer (score 0):

I used a function similar to this to create a sample Twitter test account insid of unit or integration tests:

```
static func addTestAccount(completion: ()->()) {
    let credential = ACAccountCredential(OAuthToken: TestAccountToken, tokenSecret: TestAccountSecret)
    let store = ACAccountStore()
    let type = store.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)
    let newAccount = ACAccount(accountType: type)
    newAccount.credential = credential
    newAccount.username = TestAccountUsername

    store.saveAccount(newAccount, withCompletionHandler: { (success, error) -> Void in
        print(success ? "Saved new account" : "Failed to save account \(error)")
        completion()
    })
}
```